# function CIN gets skipped every time

Tags: c++

I wanted to make a small "game" with a little bit of story, but I did some code and I think i did some major mistakes, here's the code

```
int main() {
char o, z, q, r;
string f, w = "yes", e = "no";

cout << "Hello, summoner!" << endl;
cin >> o;

cout << "You know why you are here, right?" << endl;
cin >> q;

switch ( z ) {

case 'w':
    cout << "Ok";
    break;

case 'e':
    cout << "You are here to fight for your life!";
    break;

    }
return 0;
}
```

The second `cin`, the `cin >> q;` gets skipped every time I run the code and I don't know what to do.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "gets skipped" ? Please include your input, output and expected output in the quesiton

Comment: btw using single letter variable names only is a good way to confuse the reader of your code. Lazyness doesn't always pay off

Comment: Well, you read `o` and `q`, but then have `switch ( z )`. Try to give you variables meaningfull names.

Comment: When i hit run and enter a text for the first cin, the program ends just with the second cout, and won't let me enter other text for that cin

Comment: what is the input? Do you perhaps enter more than a single character for the first input?

Comment: @PNDarius The variable z is not initialized.

Comment: No, i just say "hi" and enter

Comment: sorry I misread the code (because it is really hard to read). `o` is a single character, it cannot store "Hi"

Comment: so should i initialize ```o``` as string?

Comment: `'e'` and `'w'` are character literals. They have nothing to do with your variables `e` and `w`. Read a bit more in your favourite [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not get skipped. You may be entering more than one characters in 'o', which is not allowed in your case and the second character automatically is stored in variable q.
Try changing the data type of the variables mentioned if you want to enter longer strings in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The second `cin` does not get skipped! When you enter `"Hi"` then `std::cin >> o;` will read `'H'` while `'i'` is still left in the stream. Then `std::cin >> q;` will read that `'i'`. You can see the effect here:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char first,second;
    std::cin >> first;
    std::cin >> second;
    std::cout << first << " " << second;
}
```

When you type `Hi` then press enter the output will be

```
H i
```

If you want to store more than a single character then do not use `char`. For elaborated input checking you can use `std::getline` to read the whole line of user input and then check if it was a single character, a whole word, or something else.

PS: Don't use single letter variable names only. This is confusing and makes your code very hard to read and understand.

PPS: No offense, but don't make assumptions on what your code does. Instead use a debugger to see what actually happens. And try to be more precise on what you provide as input and what happens then. Your interpretation of "cin gets skipped" is off, and you could have seen this by inspecting the values of `o` and `q` after both `cin`s.